# Java OCR to detect Sudoku grid digits

Tags: java, ocr, tesseract

I use Tess4j to do optical recognition, it works very well for almost pictures that I give to my program. I cut the Sudoku scanned grid in 81 boxes. But, when I take a square containing a digit, Tess4j fails to detect the number. I don't know why, the digits are black on a white background. Can anyone help me please ?

Thanks for your responses !

Answer (score 0):

You can try various page segmentation modes (PSM) that Tesseract has to obtain optimal results.

```
pagesegmode values are:
0 = Orientation and script detection (OSD) only.
1 = Automatic page segmentation with OSD.
2 = Automatic page segmentation, but no OSD, or OCR
3 = Fully automatic page segmentation, but no OSD. (Default)
4 = Assume a single column of text of variable sizes.
5 = Assume a single uniform block of vertically aligned text.
6 = Assume a single uniform block of text.
7 = Treat the image as a single text line.
8 = Treat the image as a single word.
9 = Treat the image as a single word in a circle.
10 = Treat the image as a single character.
```